# How to fix vulnerabilities found in DevOps container scans when they appear to come from dotnet-core runtime config files and not my actual project?

Tags: security, .net-core, azure-devops, dotnetcorecli, trivy

So when running a Trivy container scan on my dockerised dotnet 6 app during my devops pipeline, many times I discover critical vulnerabilities which break the build and I am not sure how to fix as they do not relate to files or dependencies in my project, but from DevOps or dotnet runtime configs itself.

Here are 3 critical vulnerabilities which are inside the runtime configuration files I think, but we do not use `starkbank-ecdsa` anywhere, and the senior dev also has no idea why it is there either.

[image: screenshot of trivy container scan from devops]

I can easily disable the scanning as I do when a deployment needs to happen, but this is not the ideal solution as I would rather have any issues fixed.

I have searched online but cant seem to find a straight forward answer to how I can fix these issues. Any help or some clarity on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If Trivy finds it then odds are that the code is actually somewhere in your container, even if you think you don't need it. It's probably a transitive dependency of some other library you use. I don't know .NET build systems, but have you tried pinning the version to the "fixed version" and rebuilding?

Comment: This is what I mean though, I have no idea where this is so have no way to update the version to the fixed one, this would have been my first solution otherwise. Maybe I am just inexperienced, but I cant locate anywhere to make a change to fix this, its definitely not in our dependency list

Comment: That's why I expect it to be a transitive dependency (i.e. a dependency of one of your dependencies). I don't know how any of the .NET build systems work, so I can't give you specifics, but it should have some way to list all the dependencies and the transitive dependencies they pull in.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at a way to list all transitive deps and see if I can find it in there

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have posted the answer with some info, you were correct. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The package was indeed a transitive package which is why I couldn't find it at first. In case this helps anyone, I was able to find it within azure devops by adding the `dotnet list package --include-transitive` command into the pipeline.

[image: devops solution]

I was then able to find the package and its reference and upgrade as required. Thank you to @Joachim Sauer for the clarity.